# How to uninstall ASP.NET Core 3.1 on ubuntu20.04

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, uninstallation

I want to install .NET Core 5.0.
That's why I need to uninstall previous version .NET Core 3.1.

How to uninstall  ASP.NET Core 3.1 on ubuntu20.04?

In my PC,

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
     3.1.413 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/141/sdk]

$ dotnet --list-runtimes
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/141/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
     Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [/snap/dotnet-sdk/141/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I tried with these commands
`sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-sdk-3.1.413` and
`sudo apt remove --purge dotnet-runtime-3.1.19`

Error occurs:

> `E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-3.1.413`
>
> `E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-3.1.413'`
>
> `E: Unable to locate package dotnet-runtime-3.1.19`
>
> `E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-runtime-3.1.19'`

NOTE :`.NET Uninstall Tool` supports Windows and macOS. Linux is currently not supported.

Comment: Try solution described here: [How to remove the .NET Runtime and SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-linux#uninstall-net)

Comment: Maybe check what package you actually installed originally using e.g. `apt list --installed` or aptitude and then remove that?

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu

```sh
# List all installed packages
sudo apt --installed list

# List all the packages you installed
sudo apt --installed list | grep "dotnet-dev"
sudo apt --installed list | grep "dotnet"

# Remove a specific package
sudo apt-get remove --purge PACKAGE_NAME
```

For example

```sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge dotnet-dev-1.0.1
```

I haven't Ubuntu now, let's change commands what suite your context.

If you catch

```
Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-3.1.413
```

You can use command

```
which dotnet-sdk-3.1.413
```

to see where it stands.